# ESP8266 - Keeloq Encryption, problem with different serialnumbers

Tags: c, encryption, arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

I am using an ESP8266 microcontroller to control my shutters via radio transmitter. The shutters use the Keeloq encryption method.
I am able to control my shutters perfectly fine, the only issue is that I am limited to a specific serial number which is a result of the code I am using. The shutters itselves are able to receive commands from several serial numbers.

Whenever I send a UDP packet with 'i= 12345600' it generates 16 serials from 12345601 to 12345615 and puts it into the EEPROM. The encryption succeeds and the shutters react.
Whenever I set it to anything other but 12345600 the shutters ignore my commands.
It seems like the serial numbers 12345600-12345600 are also part of the 'fixed' encryption method and it fails whenever it doesn't match the 123456xx.
I didn't write the sketch myself, but I am banging my head against the wall for a few hours now. Help would be very appreciated.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ELECHOUSE_CC1101_SRC_DRV.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
extern "C" {
#include <Wire.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "c_types.h"
#include "ets_sys.h"
#include "os_type.h"
#include "osapi.h"
#include "mem.h"
#include "user_interface.h"
#include "smartconfig.h"
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <KeeloqLib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
}


int esp;
int pin;
short transmitPin = 5;
#define MasterMSB        0x12345678
#define MasterLSB        0x87654321
#define Lowpulse         400                //Defines Pulse-Width in us. Adapt for your use...
#define Highpulse        800
#define BITS_SIZE          8
int device_key_msb = 0x0; //stores cryptkey MSB
int device_key_lsb = 0x0; //stores cryptkey LSB
uint64_t    button = 0x0; //1000=0x8 up, 0100=0x4 stop, 0010=0x2 down, 0001=0x1 learning
unsigned int devcnt = 0x0;  //Initial 16Bit countervalue, will be loaded in EEPROM and incrementet once in a time a command is send
int disc = 0x0;
uint32_t dec = 0;  //stores the 32Bit encrypted code
uint64_t pack = 0; //Contains data to send.
byte disc_low[16] = { 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,  0x0,  0x0,  0x0 };
byte disc_high[16] = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,  0x0,  0x0,  0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, 0x8, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80 };
byte serials[16] = { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4,  0x5,  0x6,  0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC,  0xD,  0xE,  0xF }; //Represents Last Serial Digit in Binary 1234567[8] = 0xF
byte disc_l = 0;
byte disc_h = 0;
byte adresses[] = { 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 35, 41, 47, 53, 59, 65, 71, 77, 85, 91, 97 }; //Defines Start Addresses of Channel data stored in EEPROM 4bytes s/n.
char new_serial1[9];
char packet[2];
char group[9];
uint64_t new_serial = 0;
int z;
int cntadr = 110;//Where the 16Bit Counter is stored.

void setup()
{
  #ifdef ESP8266
esp = 1; pin = 5;  // for esp8266! Transmit on pin 5 = D1
#else
esp = 0; pin = 6;  // for Arduino! Transmit on pin 6.
#endif  
  Serial.begin(115200);  
  pinMode(transmitPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(transmitPin, LOW);
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.Init();
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.setMHZ(433.92);
  ELECHOUSE_cc1101.SetTx();
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password, 0, ap_mac);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);

  }
    EEPROM.begin(230);
    EEPROM.get(cntadr, devcnt);
    EEPROM.end();
    delay(50);
}

void loop() {  
  int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize)
  {
    // receive incoming UDP packets   
    int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        incomingPacket[len] = 0;
        shutters();
    } 
    }   
  yield();
  }

void shutters() { 
 
    if (incomingPacket[0] == 'l') {
        packet[0] = (incomingPacket[1]);
        packet[1] = (incomingPacket[2]);
        p = atoi(packet);
        if (p <= 15) {
            new_serial = EEPROM.get(adresses[p], new_serial);
            EEPROM.get(cntadr, devcnt);
            disc_l = disc_low[p];
            disc_h = disc_high[p];
            disc = (disc_l << 8) | serials[p];
            keygen();
            button = 0x1;
            keeloq();
            send();
            devcnt++;
            EEPROM.put(cntadr, devcnt);
            EEPROM.commit();    
        }
    } 

  //Generates 16 Serials for controlling up to 16 devices;<---Providing first serial. Enter Serial ending with 00 to simplify Grouping.
  else if (incomingPacket[0] == 'i') {
    new_serial1[0] = (incomingPacket[2]);
    new_serial1[1] = (incomingPacket[3]);
    new_serial1[2] = (incomingPacket[4]);
    new_serial1[3] = (incomingPacket[5]);
    new_serial1[4] = (incomingPacket[6]);
    new_serial1[5] = (incomingPacket[7]);
    new_serial1[6] = (incomingPacket[8]);
    new_serial1[7] = (incomingPacket[9]);
    z = atoi(new_serial1);//Conversion of new_serial to integer [1][2][3] = 123
                //Generation of 16 serial numbers and storage in EEPROM

    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; ++i) {
      EEPROM.put(adresses[i], z);//Serial 4Bytes
      z++;
    }
    EEPROM.put(cntadr, 0x0);
    delay(100);
    EEPROM.commit();    
  } 
}

//Generation of the encrypted message (Hopcode)
int keeloq() {
  Keeloq k(device_key_msb, device_key_lsb);
  unsigned int result = (disc << 16) | devcnt;  //Append counter value to discremination value
  dec = k.encrypt(result);
  return 0;
}

//Keygen generates the Device Crypt Key in relation to the Master Key and provided Serial Number.
//Here Normal Key-Generation is used acc. to 00745a_c.PDF Appendix G.
int keygen() {
  Keeloq k(MasterMSB, MasterLSB);
  uint64_t keylow = new_serial | 0x20000000;
  unsigned long enc = k.decrypt(keylow);
  device_key_lsb = enc;//Stores LSB Device Key 16Bit
  keylow = new_serial | 0x60000000;
  enc = k.decrypt(keylow);
  device_key_msb = enc;//Stores MSB Device Key 16Bit 
  return 0;
}

//Simple TX routine.
//Send code two times. In case of one shutter did not "hear" the command.
void send() {
  //cc1101.setTxState();
  pack = (button << 60) | (new_serial << 32) | dec;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {

    digitalWrite(4, LOW);//CC1101 in TX Mode+
    delayMicroseconds(1150);
    frame(10);
    delayMicroseconds(3500);//Waittime
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      int out = ((pack >> i) & 0x1);//Bitmask to get MSB and send it first
      if (out == 0x1)
      {
        digitalWrite(transmitPin, HIGH);//Simple encoding of Bit state 1
        delayMicroseconds(Lowpulse);
        digitalWrite(transmitPin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(Highpulse);
      }
      else
      {
        digitalWrite(transmitPin, HIGH);//Simple encoding of Bit state 0
        delayMicroseconds(Highpulse);
        digitalWrite(transmitPin, LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(Lowpulse);
      }
    }
    group_h(); //Last 8Bit. For motor 8-16.
    delayMicroseconds(2500);
  }
delay(10);
}

//Sending of high_group_bits 8-16
void group_h() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    int out = ((disc_h >> i) & 0x1);//Bitmask to get MSB and send it first
    if (out == 0x1)
    {
      digitalWrite(transmitPin, HIGH);//Simple encoding of Bit state 1
      delayMicroseconds(Lowpulse);
      digitalWrite(transmitPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(Highpulse);
    }
    else
    {
      digitalWrite(transmitPin, HIGH);//Simple encoding of Bit state 0
      delayMicroseconds(Highpulse);
      digitalWrite(transmitPin, LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(Lowpulse);
    }
  }
}

//Generates sync-pulses

void frame(int l) {
  for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    digitalWrite(transmitPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(Highpulse);
    digitalWrite(transmitPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(Lowpulse);
  }
}

//reverses incoming GroupBits
unsigned int reverseBits(unsigned int a) {
  unsigned int rev = 0;
  int i;
  /* scans each bit of the input number*/
  for (i = 0; i < BITS_SIZE - 1; i++)
  {
    /* checks if the bit is 1 */
    if (a & (1 << i))
    {
      /* shifts the bit 1, starting from the MSB to LSB
      to build the reverse number
      */
      rev |= 1 << (BITS_SIZE - 1) - i;
    }
  }
  return rev;
}

//Fast lookup-table for reversing the groupbits
unsigned char reverse_byte(unsigned char x)
{
  static const unsigned char table[] = {
    0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xc0, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x60, 0xe0,
    0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xd0, 0x30, 0xb0, 0x70, 0xf0,
    0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xc8, 0x28, 0xa8, 0x68, 0xe8,
    0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xd8, 0x38, 0xb8, 0x78, 0xf8,
    0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xc4, 0x24, 0xa4, 0x64, 0xe4,
    0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xd4, 0x34, 0xb4, 0x74, 0xf4,
    0x0c, 0x8c, 0x4c, 0xcc, 0x2c, 0xac, 0x6c, 0xec,
    0x1c, 0x9c, 0x5c, 0xdc, 0x3c, 0xbc, 0x7c, 0xfc,
    0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xc2, 0x22, 0xa2, 0x62, 0xe2,
    0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xd2, 0x32, 0xb2, 0x72, 0xf2,
    0x0a, 0x8a, 0x4a, 0xca, 0x2a, 0xaa, 0x6a, 0xea,
    0x1a, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0xda, 0x3a, 0xba, 0x7a, 0xfa,
    0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xc6, 0x26, 0xa6, 0x66, 0xe6,
    0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xd6, 0x36, 0xb6, 0x76, 0xf6,
    0x0e, 0x8e, 0x4e, 0xce, 0x2e, 0xae, 0x6e, 0xee,
    0x1e, 0x9e, 0x5e, 0xde, 0x3e, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0xfe,
    0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xc1, 0x21, 0xa1, 0x61, 0xe1,
    0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xd1, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x71, 0xf1,
    0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xc9, 0x29, 0xa9, 0x69, 0xe9,
    0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xd9, 0x39, 0xb9, 0x79, 0xf9,
    0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xc5, 0x25, 0xa5, 0x65, 0xe5,
    0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xd5, 0x35, 0xb5, 0x75, 0xf5,
    0x0d, 0x8d, 0x4d, 0xcd, 0x2d, 0xad, 0x6d, 0xed,
    0x1d, 0x9d, 0x5d, 0xdd, 0x3d, 0xbd, 0x7d, 0xfd,
    0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xc3, 0x23, 0xa3, 0x63, 0xe3,
    0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xd3, 0x33, 0xb3, 0x73, 0xf3,
    0x0b, 0x8b, 0x4b, 0xcb, 0x2b, 0xab, 0x6b, 0xeb,
    0x1b, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xdb, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0xfb,
    0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xc7, 0x27, 0xa7, 0x67, 0xe7,
    0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xd7, 0x37, 0xb7, 0x77, 0xf7,
    0x0f, 0x8f, 0x4f, 0xcf, 0x2f, 0xaf, 0x6f, 0xef,
    0x1f, 0x9f, 0x5f, 0xdf, 0x3f, 0xbf, 0x7f, 0xff,
  };
  return table[x];
}
```